# Transforming the right Ctrl key into a Ctrl lock key on Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like my right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to behave like the <kbd>Caps</kbd> key.  When I press it, it is as if I hold the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. And when I press it again, it release the lock.

Is there a way to do that, but only for the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (not the left one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) to do this. A basic toggle script:

```
x = 0

RCtrl::
if x {
    SendInput {Ctrl up}
    x = 0
} else {
    SendInput {Ctrl down}
    x = 1
}
return
```

1. Install Autohotkey
2. Save the script somewhere as a `.ahk` file
3. Run it by double clicking (opening) the `.ahk` file
4. If you want it to run at startup, [add it to the start menu startup folder](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#Startup)

You can replace the `SendInput` `Ctrl`s with `LCtrl`s if you want it to specifically 'hold' the left control key. It's not case sensitive, by the way.

---

If you don't wish to install Autohotkey, [here's a standalone executable](http://www.mediafire.com/?vu50ne2vh1tbql7) of the above I generated using Autohotkey's compile function. Use it in the same way the `.ahk` was described above. Use at your own risk.

---

To block the left control key while control is locked:

```
x = 0

RCtrl::
if x {
    SendInput {Ctrl up}
    x = 0
} else {
    SendInput {Ctrl down}
    x = 1
}
return

*$LCtrl::
if (!x) {
    SendInput {LCtrl down}
}
return

*$LCtrl up::
if (x && !GetKeyState("Ctrl")) {
    SendInput {Ctrl down}
} else if (!x) {
    SendInput {LCtrl up}
}
return
```

Yea... it got complicated. To make holding the key work as usual, it's necessary to hook and pass on both the down and up events. The non-blocking modifier (`~`) cannot be used, because we need to block on certain cases. To make things worse, pressing `Alt` + `Ctrl` does something weird where the control key is blocked, but... things break when it's released. The `GetKeyState` checks if it's up when it's supposed to be down, and sets it to down if it's wrong. Yep, complicated.

It probably would have been easier to just reset the lock state when the left control key is released. Ah well.

Comment: It *would* be nice to know what the downvote is for.

Comment: This is just perfect, thanks! I even used the scroll lock key to display the state of the Ctrl key.

Comment: I've just noticed, be warned that if you press the left control it will end up sending a Ctrl Up, unlocking it.. so catch the `~Ctrl Up` hotkey and use that to turn off your scroll lock light. Or catch `LCtrl` and block it completely when the lock is active.

Comment: I'm really struggling with the "blocking" of the left key :'(. Here is a part of my code: `LCtrl:: if x {} else { Send {LCtrl} }`. Now the left Ctrl key doesn't work at all :(

Comment: Yea, it gets complicated. I've edited in a version that blocks the left control key when locked. For future reference, when you do nothing (`{}`), you're blocking the key. When you send `{LCtrl}`, you're sending a press *and immediate* release. To simulate holding you have to hook both key up and key down.